# crystal reports with Visual Studio 2010 A5 page orientation issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a report which needs to be exported to PDF in 8" * 5.5", Portrait orientation. Now in Crystal Reports 13 (VS2010) when I choose page size as A5 and orientation as Portrait it still prints in Landscape orientation. I tried creating user defined page size with above dimension, it chooses Landscape automatically.

What could be the solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting the page orientation from code behind when you actually set the ReportViewer report.

```
ReportDocument rpt = new WhateverthenameofReport();
rpt.ReportDefinition.Sections[index of the report section].SectionFormat.PageOrientation = ""; // This can be the name of the orientation
```

Comment: well its an issue with VS version. I downloaded the full version, It works fine there.